# How to regularize 'fitcecoc' using templateSVM in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm

I am using polynomial SVM in MATLAB for CIFAR-10 dataset using HOG features for data extraction. I wanted to know how I can tune the regularization parameters for 'fitcecoc' to avoid overfitting the training set.

```
template = templateSVM(...
'KernelFunction', 'polynomial', ...
'PolynomialOrder', 2, ...
'KernelScale', 'auto', ...
'BoxConstraint', 1, ...
'Standardize', true);
SVM_model = fitcecoc(...
X_train, ...
Y_train, ...
'Learners', template, ...
'Coding', 'onevsone', ...
'Verbose', 2,...
'ClassNames', [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10]);
```